# F9 key in google sheets to evaluate partial function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know if you highlight in google sheets it gives you the F9 output but only visually, what if I want to evaluate a part of a formula is there an equivalent to F9 or an easy way to do this without having to dissect the entire formula?

Comment: No, Apps Script doesn't has any built-in function to do that. You'd need to dissect the formula or the part of the formula you need to calculate.

Comment: @AndresDuarte interestingly F9 does turn on formula preview but it only works for certain things and I guess the output needs to fit in the little box.

Comment: Yes, but what you want is a way to get the result for parts of the formula (result preview) with Apps Script right?

Comment: @AndresDuarte yes, that or any other way I can't think of. I guess I really miss the evaluate formula feature too!